# make directory or subdomain for every use

Tags: php

i am a beginner at web developing but trying to improve my skills,
To make a simple page that view a users data from database i will had to use GET method  like that:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM series WHERE seriesID = $id");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

something like: users.php?id=1 but i saw some website uses a different ways
1- the first way is to make it looks like a directory 
ex. www.website.com/username/
2- make a sub-domain for every user
ex. username.website.com
i hope you understand what i'm saying

edit: i understand the pretty urls now but i still don't know how to make a subdomain for every registered member

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: You should also be aware of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1]).